# How to search for two or more whitespace and the pointer ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to read a .txt file and search for two or more whitespace in each line and saving the pointer where that match occurs, using stringScanner gem

Until now I have manage to find the match but I can't figure it out how to save the pointer

```
require 'strscan'

class LintFile
  attr_reader :file, :lines
  def initialize(filepath)
    @file = File.open(filepath)
    @lines = []
  end

  def read
    # Here I get each line into an array
    @file.each_with_index do |line, ind|
       @lines[ind] = StringScanner.new(line)
    end
  end
end

def check_error(filepath)
    @file_to_check = LintFile.new(filepath)
    @file_to_check.read
    #file_to_check.lines
  
    #Scan each line
    @file_to_check.lines.length.times do |line|
      whitespace(line)
    end
end

def whitespace(line)
  if @file_to_check.lines[line].string.match?("  ")
    #pos is not giving the pointer where the match occurred
    pointer = @file_to_check.lines[line].pos
    puts "Estoy dentro del unless #{pointer}"
  end
end
```

Please help me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the file contains a string that is read into a variable `str`. For example:

```
str =<<~_
Now is  the time for
all good Rubyists to
come    to the    aid
of their fellow    coders.
_
```

**Using [StringScanner](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) methods**

We can obtain the offsets into the string `str` of the beginning of each substring comprised of two or more spaces as follows. As will be seen, obtaining offsets *into each line* (rather than into `str`) is a straightforward modification of the calculation I will describe.

```
require 'strscan'

def scan_it(str)    
  s = StringScanner.new(str)
  arr = []
  until s.eos?
    ss = s.scan(/ {2,}/)
    if ss
      arr << s.pos - ss.size
    else
      s.scan(/ ?[^ ]+/)
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

We obtain:

```
arr = scan_it(str)
  #=> [6, 46, 56, 79]
```

Let's examine the substrings around those offsets in `str`.

```
arr.map { |n| puts str[n-3,10] }
 is  the t
ome    to 
the    aid
low    cod
```

The regular expression `/ {2,}/` matches two or more spaces. The regular expression `/ ?[^ ]+/` matches one or more (`+`) characters other than a space (`[^ ]`), optionally preceded by one space ( `?`).

The matches of `s.scan` are shown in the following table. (Underscores in the first column denote spaces.)

```
ss        regex matched    s.pos  s.pos-ss.size            
-----------------------------------------------            
Now          / ?[^ ]+/        3          
_is          / ?[^ ]+/        6
__           / {2,}/          8         6
the          / ?[^ ]+/       11 
_time        / ?[^ ]+/       16 
_for\nall    / ?[^ ]+/       24
_good        / ?[^ ]+/       29
_Rubyists    / ?[^ ]+/       38
_to\ncome    / ?[^ ]+/       46
____         / {2,}/         50        46
to           / ?[^ ]+/       52
_the         / ?[^ ]+/       56  
____         / {2,}/         60        56
aid\nof      / ?[^ ]+/       66
_their       / ?[^ ]+/       72
_fellow      / ?[^ ]+/       79
____         / {2,}/         83        79
coders.      / ?[^ ]+/       90
```

**Obtain offsets for each line**

```
str.each_line.with_index.with_object({}) do |(line,i),h|
  h[i] = scan_it(line)
end
  #=> {0=>[6], 1=>[], 2=>[4, 14], 3=>[15]}
```

This shows that there is one substring of two or more spaces in the first line (line offset `0`), beginning at offset `6`, no substrings in the second line, two in the third, beginning at offsets `4` and `14` and one in the last line, beginning at offset `15`.

See [String#each_line](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_line), [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

**Using [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)**

Here's a simpler way to compute the desired offsets that does not use `StringScanner`.

```
str.gsub(/ {2,}/).map { |_,arr| Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
  #=> [6, 46, 56, 79]
```

This uses the form of `String#gsub` that takes one argument (the pattern) and no block. This returns an enumerator which merely generates matches (each a string of two or more spaces) and performs no substitutions (making the name `gsub` somewhat confusing). I've chained the enumerator to [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Each match is held by the first block variable. I've used an underscore for that variable to signal to the reader that it's not used in the block calculation (a common practice).

See also [Regexp::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match), which returns a `MatchData` object, and [MatchData#begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-begin), which gives us the offset for the beginning of the current match.

**Obtain lines and locations within lines of substrings of two or more spaces begin**

```
str.each_line.with_index.with_object({}) do |(line,i),h|
  h[i] = line.gsub(/ {2,}/).map { |_,arr| Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
end
  #=> {0=>[6], 1=>[], 2=>[4, 14], 3=>[15]}
```

Comment: Thanks the string#sub description saved me hours of research!